# How does CSS deal with classes of the same name

Tags: html, css

I thought I understood this, but clearly not.

Take the code below. I have two header classes. However, one is a descendant of homecompcol. This is inheriting the 100px height from the global class, header.

```
.header {
   height: 100px;
}

.homecompcol .header {
   font-size: 35px;
   font-family: 'montserratblack';
   text-transform: uppercase;
   display: block;
   border: #C37C7E solid thin;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="homecompcol">
<div class="header">Test</div>
</div>
```

What is the point of nested classes if they inherit from elsewhere?

Should I simply not re-use class names?

Comment: Everything with `class="header"` (or a class list including `header`) is matched by `.header`. Only things with `class="header"` (or ...) *inside* things with `class="homecompcol"` (or ...) are matched by `.homecompcol .header`.

Comment: The point of a _selector_ like `.homecompcol .header` would be, that all properties you specify in that rule, apply only to elements with the class `header`, that are a descendant of an element with the class `homecompcol`. This does not _invalidate_ the simpler selector `.header`, what you specify via that, still applies to _all_ elements with the class `header`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine if you have a page with complex design and lots of content. You have a many elements with the class names of `.header` like one is the main header for the page and again for the header of the posts, sidebar widgets etc.

If you directly style `.header` it will try to match all the elements with this class and try to style that all now how you specify that you want to style the main header or only post header then this type of selectors will comes to rescue.

You can style for the main header which is nested inside the `.main` a section like `.main .header` this will specify that you want to style the class nested in the main section.

Similarly, for the posts and sidebar, you can style the same class but specifically of that region.

You can use id, other attributes sectors but this question scope is related to the class that's why answering in limitation.

```css
/* Styling Globally all alements with the class header*/
.header{

}

/* Styling specfically posts header*/
.posts .header{
  
}

/* Styling specifically sidebar header*/
.sidebar .header{

}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='header'>
  <h1>Main Header</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='posts'>
  <div class='header'>
  <h2>Post Title</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='sidebar'>
  <div class='header'>
  <h2>Widget Title</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I appreciate your time